# cURL example of posting photos remotely to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, curl, photos

I am currently having a problem, where I try to post a picture to Facebook and I get an "error" response:

```
"Requires upload file", with OAuth exception #324.
```

I have the access token in there just fine and I can adapt my code from a `cURL` example relatively easily. All the examples I can find show how to do it in PHP (which I don't know) or something of the like. Any help with an example of how to upload a photo just from the `cURL` command line tool would be greatly appreciated.

I just can't find what I am looking for anywhere for the life of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you appending with the `@` character?

```
curl -F 'access_token=xxx' \ 
     -F 'source=@img.jpg' \
     -F 'message=Test' 
     'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos'
```

Comment: The FB API is new to me what do you do If you want to attach more than one image?